# OSX: CMake+RPath confusion

Tags: xcode, macos, cmake

I have a cmake project that is building, but at runtime (for ex, when running my unit tests executable) it is not able to link one of my dylib dependencies.  Looking at the output of "otool -L" I see a long list of deps prefixed with @rpath except for one offending set of libs (which all came from same package) that do not have that.  Here is a representative example, where the offenders are the libicu* libs:

`@rpath/libboost_date_time.dylib ...
libicui18n.44.dylib ...
libicuio.44.dylib ...
@rpath/libQt5DBus_debug.5.dylib ...`

Is there anything I can do at build time to get that @rpath prefix on those deps?  Looking at the [cmake RPATH docs](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_RPATH_handling) it sounds to me like the RPATH can be set, but by default it will be correct, including all linked lib paths... it isn't clear to me how to make sure the libs themselves use the rpath.  Is there anything I can do at build time to make sure that the @rpath prefix is on the dep name?

Answer (score 0):

CMake has some special magic since version 2.8.12 which got additional settings later on and quickliy established as a default.

The proprty MACOSX_RPATH is used on targets to initialize rpath correctly on OSX.

The Policy CMP0042 controls if this is defautl behavior or not.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/prop_tgt/MACOSX_RPATH.html#prop_tgt:MACOSX_RPATH
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/policy/CMP0042.html